# Правильно ли я реализовал Observer Design Pattern

Tags: php, шаблоны-проектирования

Давно решил понять как работает **Observer Design Pattern**.И вот решил покопаться в нем.

Тут я пытаюсь организовать подписчиков на выход новой газеты.

Можно ли этот код принять за реализацию Pattern Шаблона наблюдателя,или это тупо использование [Интерфейс SplObserver](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.splobserver.php)

```
<?php
    //Uroven 4  lesson-2
    class Subject implements SplSubject
    {
        private $observers,$value;
        public function __construct(){
            $this->observers=array();
        }
        public function attach(SplObserver $observer){
            $this->observers[]=$observer;
        }
        public function detach(SplObserver $observer){
            if($id=array_search($observer,$this->observers,true)){
                unset($this->observers[$id]);
            }
        }
        public function notify(){
            foreach($this->observers as $observer){
                $observer->update($this);
            }
        }
        public function setValue($value){
            $this->value=$value;
            $this->notify();
        }
        public function getValue(){
            return $this->value;
        }
    }
    class Observer implements SplObserver{
        public function update(SplSubject $subject){
            echo '<p>Novaya statya '.$subject->getValue().'</p>';
        }
    }
    $magazin = new Subject();

    $vasya=new Observer();
    $magazin->attach($vasya);
    $magazin->detach($vasya);
    $magazin->setValue("Article number 1");

    $petya=new Observer();
    $magazin->attach($petya);
    $magazin->setValue("Article number 2");
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте разберемся, что такое паттерн наблюдатель. Говоря простым языком, у нас есть объект, за которым мы хотим мониторить (наблюдать) на предмет каких-либо изменений.

Реализация паттерна Observer представляет собой связь «один-ко-многим» и реализуется с помощью нескольких классов. Один из них – Субъект. Класс Субъект информирует другие классы, которые называются Наблюдателями, о каких-либо событиях, произошедших внутри себя.

Субъект должны наследовать и реализовывать интерфейс, описывающий методы, с помощью которых Наблюдатели будут с ним взаимодействовать. Наблюдатели, в свою очередь, наследуют и реализуют другой интерфейс, описывающий метод, с помощью которого Субъект уведомляет Наблюдателей о событиях.

У вас метод **Subject**::setValue() якобы выполняет обновление какого-то либо значения и оповещает других об этом.

Методы **Subject**::detach() и **Subject**::attach() позволяют добавлять наблюдателей в стэк (массив) и удалять их оттуда в случае необходимости. Метод **Subject**::notify() запускает цикл обхода Наблюдателей по списку и отправки уведомления каждому из них с помощью публичного метода **Observer**::update().

В целом все правильно, но я бы observers вместо массива заменил бы на \SplObjectStorage(), так работать намного удобнее:

```
<?php

class Subject implements \SplSubject
{

    protected $value;

    /**
     * @var \SplObjectStorage
     */
    protected $observers;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->observers = new \SplObjectStorage();
    }

    public function attach(\SplObserver $observer)
    {
        $this->observers->attach($observer);
    }

    public function detach(\SplObserver $observer)
    {
        $this->observers->detach($observer);
    }

    public function notify()
    {
        /** @var \SplObserver $observer */
        foreach ($this->observers as $observer) {
            $observer->update($this);
        }
    }

    public function setValue($value){
        $this->value=$value;
        $this->notify();
    }

}
```

Comment: SplObjectStorage Не пользовался.Исправлю :).Спасибо,главное я на верном пути.Я тут хочу аутентификацию через него исполнить.Пусть он следит кто вышел кто вошел.Спасибо

Comment: Единственная ошибка в проектировании, что вы передаете в update SplSubject, но вызываете метод getValue, который относиться к Subject. Нужно реализовать такой интерфейс или изменить update(SplSubject $subject) на update(Subject $subject), так как нет гарантии что у класс реализующего splSubject будет этот метод getValue

Comment: Я передаю объект типа SplSubject  а не просто SplSubject.class Subject относится к этому типу.Я говорю что в update я принимаю объекты только этого типа.В программировании это называют  Контроль типа  http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.typehinting.php

Comment: Вы передаете объект типа splSubject, но вызываете метод из Subject, который не определен в splSubject

Comment: Он от него наследует ,а значит принадлежит этому типу

Comment: Вы ожидаете в функции экземлпяр который наследует интерфейс SplSubject, который имеет только методы attach, deattach, notify, а оказывается ожидаете Subject, и вызываете метод getValue который не определен в интерфейсе который вы ждете.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43462/discussion-between-vanya-avchyan-and-firepro).